# Cannot add a BufferGeometry in Point component from React-Three-drei and React Three Fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm working on a project react-three-fiber and drei for making a realistic rain effect. When I'm trying to implement a geometry in Point Component from drei, I get a black page. No scene shown on browser

This is my code:

```
const RainScene = () => {

  // Initialize rain particles
  const rainCount = 1500;

  const rainGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  
  const positions = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < rainCount; i++) {
    const rainDrop = new THREE.Vector3(
      Math.random() * 400 - 200,
      Math.random() * 500 - 250,
      Math.random() * 400 - 200
    );
    positions.push(rainDrop.x, rainDrop.y, rainDrop.z);
  }

  const positionAttribute = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions), 3);
  rainGeo.setAttribute('position', positionAttribute);

  return (
    <>
      <group>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.55} />
        <directionalLight position={[0, 0, 1]} color={0xffeedd} />
        <Points
          limit={1000} // Optional: max amount of items (for calculating buffer size)
          range={1000} // Optional: draw-range
          geometry={rainGeo}
        >
          <pointsMaterial/>
        </Points>
      </group>
    </>
  );
};

export default RainScene;
```

Comment: Well, what appears in the browser console? An error message, perhaps?

Comment: No. I have no error. My RainGeo geometry is just not rendered on the browser. I think I should add something to make it appear